# Problem about basic probability

Tags: probability

I have this problem about probability:

> Three dresses are required for three dancers, one size xs, one size s
>   and one size m. Yes Each dress arrives in a box and it is impossible
>   to see the size, what is the probability of that by handing them over
>   at random, only one dancer receives her correct dress?

I'm stuck with this exercise.

My only development, so far is:

Here are 3 possible cases for this: `IIC - ICI - CII`, where `I` means incorrect dress and `C` correct dress.

Comment: Hint: Consider all possibilities. How many different possible outcomes are there? For example, one outcome is that all dances get their respective dress. You've come up with the three outcomes for the event where exactly one dancer gets her respective dress; now figure out how many other possibilities there are.

Comment: and how can I find out? I'm stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that there are $3! = 6$ ways to hand out the dresses. If you want only 1 dancer to get the correct dress, then that means the other dancers much have switched, leaving only $3$ cases, leaving the solution as $\boxed{\frac{1}{2}}$

Comment: why 3!? CCC, CII, IIC, III, ICI, ICC, CCI... there are more of 3! possible cases, can you explain me please

Comment: @Mattiu how can there be only one person with an incorrect dress? Can you give an example?

Comment: @Mattiu If you have 2 Correct dresses, the last one has to be correct. This is just a question of ordering the 3 dresses

Comment: I'm still without undestand why there are 3! ways

Comment: I have this: CCC, III, IIC, CII, ICI, that are 5

Comment: III is not 1 case, there are multiple ways to get III. Just simply think 3 dancers labeled ABC with 3 dress labeled 123. How many ways can you sort them to give them in order?